# Jetpack compose DropdownMenu for big data

Tags: asynchronous, android-jetpack-compose, dropdown

I have a problem with bid data loading on DropdownMenu.
I have approximately 500 items in list and then I'm loading it on dropdown menu it's take some time, and it's lagging.
How can I do async show on drop menu?
Show some count of data, and then in background load additional or by the scroll?

```
val suggestions = viewModel.names.collectAsState().value
DropdownMenu(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(400.dp)
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
                ) {
                    suggestions.forEach { it ->
                        SuggestionWidget(
                            it!!.name
                        ) {

                        }
                    }
                }
```